# Using EVR mixer standalone

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

the enhanced video renderer of windows media foundation internally uses a video mixer object.
Is it possible to create a standalone version of this mixer object to mix two video streams for saving them using an archive sink?

Any help is appreciated